# How do I add weatherproof exterior soffit lights?

Tags: lighting, soffit

I want to add exterior soffit lights to my house and use Philips Hue br30 bulbs in them.

I would like a suggestions a weatherproof can and trim that might work for my scenario.

Comment: The lights would not get wet recessed in the soffits are you thinking about adding lenses to enclose the fixture?

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic. Visit your local store or your local Google.

Comment: Do you have a specific concern about any weatherproof product not working for some reason?  If you use any product sold as waterproof and designed for that purpose, why do you think there might be an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do NOT need "waterproof" recessed lights. Most can/trim combinations are damp location rated, which is what under a soffit is.

You could use a shower rated trim, but that would be completely unnecessary, restrict the light considerably, and collect bugs like no tomorrow.

Comment: What he said. At least we hope the soffit is not collecting water.